# Can I connect a smart charger to a lithium battery with a BMS

Tags: charger, discharge, lithium

I have several tools with NiCad batteries which are failing due to the age of the batteries. I refuse to throw these perfectly good tools away and wish to convert the batteries to lithium.
I HAVE LEARNED ABOUT THE DANGERS OF HANDLING LITHIUM BATTERIES.
I have a Sky B6ACV2 charger which states that it shouldn't be connected to a BMS.
If I do not incorperate a BMS into my batteries how do I avoid an over discharge and also excessive amperage draw when in use?
I apologise for my ignorance.

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason why your charger should care about the BMS unless it trips and goes open circuit.

Comment: Perhaps I have made a mistake referring to the battery BMS.    The manual states "Never attempt to charge or discharge a battery fitted with an internal charge circuit or protection circuit"

Comment: I would not worry but if in doubt - don’t.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I am concerned not to blow my charger so will err on the side of caution for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts